# pyserial on Mac osx10: serial unit not found by python idle

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyserial

hi guys am going crazy: have installed Python 2.7 on my Mac booker OS X 10.12.1 and think that I have installed pyserial and python cannot find the serial unit, but!when I do the sudo install pyserial here is the ansewer:
MacBook-Pro-de-Jean:~ jean$ pip install pyserial
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-3.4-py2.7.egg
MacBook-Pro-de-Jean:~ jean$ sudo pip install pyserial
Password:
The directory '/Users/jean/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/jean/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-3.4-py2.7.egg
MacBook-Pro-de-Jean:~ jean$

I understand from that script that it is installed so why can't I find the serial unit????

what does it mean?????

thanks a lot

jean-claude.

Comment: hi have solved the problem by reading another post and do install in pyinstall in the pyserial directory.thanks have resolved my problem as well but now python cannot do this:
arduinoSerialData =serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411',9600)

'/dev/cu.usbmodem1411'is the name used in sketch ide.

thanks for helping
jc.

Comment: have solved the next problem using this from another post:import serial.tools.list_ports
print(list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())).   it was all syntax mistakes afterwards!!yepppeeee!!!